# Function with cached return value but not locked

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a function where I would like to cache a return value because it might take awhile to fetch and doesn't need to be updated frequently. Currently, I would do something like this:

```
std::vector<Foo> getFoos() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);

    std::time_t now = std::time(0);

    if (std::difftime(now, oldTime) > CACHE_LIFESPAN) {
        cachedVector.empty();

        //do something expensive that fills up cachedVector again

        oldTime = now;
    }

    return cachedVector;
}
```

Is there some way I can achieve a similar result without having to lock the entire function?

At the very least, I'd like the function to be effectively lockless *unless* `cachedVector` needs to be computed again, in which case any other threads either get the previous `cachedVector` or wait.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? When two threads query the value, and the first one started the retrieval, should the second one still get the old value instead of waiting? Or are you worried about the performance when the cached value is returned?

Comment: you could move `lock` to the `if`'s body to only lock when new value is needed (and double check not to calculate multiple times in sequence) and double check

Comment: @slawekwin Um.. no, he can't. You introduce a race on `oldTime` if you do that, which is pretty much what the OP is trying to avoid. The lock isn't just protecting the vector; it's also protecting `oldTime`. The existing code at-beast could have the lock moved past the acquisition of `now`, but that's it. He needs at least one atomic, some non-trivial sequencing, and still needs the mutex to do this the way it seems to be desired.

Comment: Can you explain what you'd like to get outside of the lock? Is it the copying of the vector that's expensive?

Comment: yes, @WhozCraig described what i want.

Comment: @Karsten Koop, im basically seeing if there is a way to improve the performance when retrieving the old value because the vast majority of the time that is what will be happening. but, the old value does need to be updated periodically.

Comment: @tau That's doable, assuming the copying of the `vector` really is expensive enough to be worth optimizing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz im not worried about the copy of the vector because the vector ends up being pretty small. im just seeing if there is a way to optimize this function for the common case (old value is returned without doing the expensive calculation of old value). right now i have to lock every time it is called even though the vast majority of the time old value is returned.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't take very long to copy the vector a spinlock might be more efficient.

Comment: Ok, just to clear up the otherwise somewhat muddy water, is your goal here to avoid the *mutex* latch in favor of something less sledge-hammer-ish either (a) entirely, or (b) until such time as an expiration is detected and the vector needs reloading? That's kind of where I see this is heading, but to be sure, your question needs some detailed clarification (ideally, updated *in the question itself*).

Comment: @tau I don't get it then. If it's not the copy of the vector that you care about, what are you trying to optimize? What are you doing while holding the lock that you would prefer to do without holding the lock?!

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, (b) is what i was thinking, although im open to other ideas. possibly i can do some atomic swapping of pointers or something, but that is actually my problem: i dont know how to do that (or the best way to do it at least). ill update the question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is c++11 compliant, you could use static thread local cache to avoid the mutex but the 'something expensive' would be executed once per thread.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration for more information ( thread_local keyword ).

Answer (score 0):

Change `cachedVector` to be a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Foo>>`. Then change the code as follows:

```
std::vector<Foo> getFoos()
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Foo>> ret;
    std::time_t now = std::time(0);
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);

        if (std::difftime(now, oldTime) > CACHE_LIFESPAN)
        {
            std::vector<Foo> newVector;

            //do something expensive that fills up newVector

            cachedVector = std::make_shared<std::vector<Foo>>(newVector);
            oldTime = now;
        }
        ret = cachedVector;
    }
    return *ret;
}
```

This way, the vector is copied without holding the lock.

Comment: I *think* the OP is trying to make the in-and-out case *lockless* unless the vector needs changing. I.e., it isn't the copying, its more a lock-only-on-reload type thing (the "// do something expensive" comment in the post). Hard saying unless the question details are considerably clearer. Either way, I see a `std::shared_ptr` in his future.